# Play Integrity Error Flutter Firebase Phone Auth

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

Hi i'm trying to setup phone auth on my app but i have an error when i'm trying to send sms code.
I have enable Play Integrity on firebase console with app fingerprint

```
I/PlayCore( 5388): UID: [10182]  PID: [5388] IntegrityService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/PlayCore( 5388): UID: [10182]  PID: [5388] IntegrityService : Failed to bind to the service.
E/zzf     ( 5388): Play Integrity Token fetch failed, falling back to Recaptcha-9: Integrity API error (-9): Binding to the service in the Play Store has failed. This can be due to having an old Play Store version installed on the device.
E/zzf     ( 5388): Ask the user to update Play Store.
E/zzf     ( 5388):  (https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/model/IntegrityErrorCode.html#CANNOT_BIND_TO_SERVICE).
E/OpenGLRenderer( 5388): Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor( 5388): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Too many attempts.
D/TrafficStats( 5388): tagSocket(167) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
W/RecaptchaActivity( 5388): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. 
E/zzf     ( 5388): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an internal error in the web widget. [ {"code":"auth/internal-error","message":"{\"error\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.\",\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.\",\"domain\":\"global\",\"reason\":\"forbidden\"}],\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"details\":[{\"@type\":\"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo\",\"reason\":\"API_KEY_ANDROID_APP_BLOCKED\",\"domain\":\"googleapis.com\",\"metadata\":{\"service\":\"identitytoolkit.googleapis.com\",\"consumer\":\"projects/891062597489\"}}]}}"} ]]- calling backend without app verification
```

I tried to add FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate but didn't work

```
void main () async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest,
  );
  runApp(

    MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => LocationProvider(), // Fournisseur pour la carte
            child: const MyApp(),
          ),
        ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
E/zzf     ( 5388): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an internal error in the web widget. [ {"code":"auth/internal-error","message":"{\"error\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.\",\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.\",\"domain\":\"global\",\"reason\":\"forbidden\"}],\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"details\":[{\"@type\":\"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo\",\"reason\":\"API_KEY_ANDROID_APP_BLOCKED\",\"domain\":\"googleapis.com\",\"metadata\":{\"service\":\"identitytoolkit.googleapis.com\",\"consumer\":\"projects/891062597489\"}}]}}"} ]]- calling backend without app verification
```

this log denote that you have tried several time to login using the same phone number and they blocked the device. Try an other device ory try after 4 hours.
In other hand you are experiencing issue with appckeck implementation. I think you are using Play Integrity method. If your app is already in playstore try to log in using play store downloaded app, other ways you need to create debug token from firebase appcheck console and need to use AndroidProvider.debug you test the functionality.Still may you can face issue related to browser.